# Map on stream of Optionals type

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, stream, option-type

I had a compiler problem which I was able to reduce to this example. This code

```
class A<T> {
    Optional<Integer> op;

    public Optional<Integer> getOp() {
        return op;
    }
}
List<A> l = null;
l.stream().map(x -> x.getOp().orElse(0)).max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

doesn't compile with

```
error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    [javac]         l.stream().map(x -> x.getOp().orElse(0)).max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    [javac]                                                                             ^
```

If I remove generic parameter `<T>` (which is not used in the class at all) then this snippet compiles. What is going on here? I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Don’t use raw types. `List<A>` has a raw type as `A` is generic. Raw types and type inference don’t play nice!

Comment: The raw type `A` in `List<A>` causes you to lose all generic information, including the return type on `getOp()`, even if it's unrelated to `T`. Also, `Optional<Integer> getOp()` *smells* when the enclosing type is `A<T>`. Shouldn't it be having something to do with `Optional<T>`?

Comment: What about using `List<A<?>>` instead of `List<A>`?

Comment: It's just an example when a generic has a method not dependent on generic type parameter. Real example looks like `class A implements Iterable<B>` where `B` is a generic interface. So `A` declaration uses "raw interface" as type parameter. I'll read up on this. Thanks!

Comment: @dan1st it works)

Comment: @dan1st `List<A>` and `List<A<?>>` are the same. You might want to use `List<A<T>>` instead. It is not clear to me what you need the `T` for, though.

Comment: It is not the same. `A` is a raw type and `A<?>` is a wildcard generic type. It seems that the raw type was the problem.